# Laravel 5.7 echo out session value in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to echo out the value of a session that I set in Controller

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $request->session()->put('locale',$request->locale);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success',('app.Locale_Change_Success'));
    } 
}
```

the Values of `$request->local` that submits by ajax are **dr** and **en**.
Now I want to the value of **dr** and **en** in blade, the code looks like this

```
@if(Session::has('locale','en'))
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/en.css">
@endif
@if(Session::has('locale','dr'))
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dr.css">
@endif
```

Comment: Has usually only accepts one variable, and does not compare it to a value. Use `Session::get('locale') == 'en'` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#using-the-session) one way to check it could be this:

```
@if(session()->has('locale'))
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/{{ session()->get('locale') }}.css">
@endif
```

This saves you duplicate code (the `<link>` tag) and is easier to read. It also saves you the hassle of checking for each possible locale you might add in the future.